# remove text in between tags on the same line

Tags: xml

I have this line from an rrd file, where I need to replace what it is in between `<v>` and `</v>`.

```
<row><v> 2.0000000000e+02 </v><v> 2.3200000000e+02 </v><v> 2.6600000000e+02 </v></row>
```

In the above line, using patterns for the presented numbers, will work with:

```
|sed -r "s/<v> [0-9]+\.[0-9]+e\+[0-9]+ <\/v>/ NaN /gI".
```

My question is on how can you replace anything in between those tags (e.g with NaN) , not knowing what the text is:

```
<row><v> some text </v><v> .8234 </v><v> FA:DD:AB </v></row>
```

Comment: Do you think `sed` is a good tool to process XML documents?

Comment: Using regex to parse XML (or HTML) outside narrow use cases can have [unfortunate effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392).

Comment: I am processing only lines based on timestamp criteria that have information like the one presented.

Comment: I was looking for a solution for this specific type of line, where there are the same multiple tags on the same line, regardless from where you take it. 
In the end, I used the below and it did the job:
> tr ">" "\n" | sed "s/ .*<\/v/ NaN <\/v/g" | tr "\n" ">"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use an XML-aware tool.

For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you'd write

```
open file.xml ;
for //v set . 'NaN' ;
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with choroba: you should always use XML-aware tools to process XML. In XSLT 3.0 this is

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="v/text()">NaN</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```